# Как сделать GridView прокручиваемым?

Tags: android, java

Заполнил GridView.
[Скриншот](http://floomby.ru/s2/seUMkH)
Но почему-то он не прокручивается. Ровно под размер экрана. По скриншоту видно, что картинки обрублены. И не сдвинуть ни на пиксель. Причем если стиль сделать с экшн баром, то можно будет крутить, но чуть-чуть (в высоту экшн бара, т.е. картинки будут так же обрублены).

**Обновление**

Содержимое, очевидно, не влезает в экран. Хочется свайпом прокрутить его, чтобы увидеть нижний край. А оно не прокручивается. Совсем. Хотя если добавить ActionBar в стиль сверху, то можно чуть-чуть двигать, но не достаточно.

Comment: Можно перефразировать? Я ничего не понял.

Comment: @Saint, а на каком слое этот GridView лежит?

Comment: Добавьте к GridView немного padding`а. Например, 20dp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть была такова, что нижней границей (до которой можно прокрутить экран) считается нижняя граница последнего вставленного View в сетку. А, как видно на скриншоте, в последней ячейке (самая правая в нижней строке) нет картинки (оказывается, сервер null присылал, поставил свою дефолтную), поэтому ячейка оказалась короткая. Поэтому экран и не прокручивался.